# WK Webview history.replaceState appends to history

Tags: javascript, react-native, webview, navigation

I'm building a react native app that renders a singe page web application inside a [webview](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview).  I want to use the `history.replaceState` method to alter the current history href, without reloading the entire page.  So the history would look like this:

```
1) ["/"]
2) ["/", "/foo"] after history.pushState
3) ["/", "/bar"] after history.replaceState
```

This works as expected on Safari and Chrome, but in the webview `replaceState` pushes a new entry to the end of the stack, so it ends up like this: `["/", "/foo", "/bar"]`

How can I have `replaceState` work as described in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState) ?